# How to make the markers toggle?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

my problem is that I have some markers that needs to toggle when I click on the button, How can I add the id and the visiblity property to these markers ? I tried adding the id directly to the markers but that didn't work and also I don't know how to add the "visibility" to the markers geojson (only for the mapboxmarker the other one is just for some testig there)
Here is the code and the js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/foyb96zq/

HTML

```
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7134867017.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="menu">
  
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

CSS

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; } 
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }

.marker {
  background-image: url('https://f.hubspotusercontent20.net/hubfs/6957522/mapbox-icon.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

    #menu {
        background: #773dbd;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 50px;
        right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: 120px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        
    }

    #menu a {
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        text-align: center;
    }
   

    #menu a:last-child {
        border: none;
    }

    #menu a:hover {
        background-color: #966acc;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    #menu a.active {
        background-color: #773dbd;
        color: #ffffff;
      
    }
  
   

    #menu a.active:hover {
        background: #966acc;
    }
  .clicked  { 
    text-align: right !important;
  
}
  .clicked::before {
    content:"\f058";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    /*--adjust as necessary--*/
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top:9px;
    left:10px;

  
}
```

JS

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYW5kcnJlIiwiYSI6ImNrYndjMm0yZzBjMHIyeW1zN3EyNWY4ODcifQ.G4ThulNR7Vi_u6zrdJ5V1w';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/andrre/ckbwd976y10g91iqmo7s17jcz',
        center: [-41.014594, 38.320168],
        zoom: 3
    });


var geojson = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [{
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [
      -73.985148,
      40.732454
    ]
    },
    properties: {
      title: 'New York',
      description: 'undefined'
    }
  },
   {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [
      -0.128754,
      51.507662
    ]
    },
    properties: {
      title: 'London',
      description: 'undefined'
    }
  },
   {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates:  [
      2.352028,
      48.857033
    ]
    },
    properties: {
      title: 'Paris',
      description: 'undefined'
    }
  }
    
   
]};


//
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

// create a HTML element for each feature
var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';
  
new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
  .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
  .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
  .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
  .addTo(map);
  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .addTo(map);
});


//code for toogle
//

// enumerate ids of the layers
var toggleableLayerIds = ['contours', 'museums'];
 
// set up the corresponding toggle button for each layer
for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];
 
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = '#';
link.className = 'active';
link.textContent = id;
 
link.onclick = function(e) {
var clickedLayer = this.textContent;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
 
var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility');
 
// toggle layer visibility by changing the layout object's visibility property
if (visibility === 'visible') {
map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
this.className = '';
} else {
this.className = 'active';
map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'visible');
}
};
 
var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
layers.appendChild(link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the markers as new feature layers, not just add them one-by-one in a for loop. The above code is erroring as you have not added any layers, and mapbox doesn't know how it is mean to group your markers.

See the [docs here](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/markers-js/#add-markers-with-geojson-in-mapboxjs) for info.

Comment: I think he will need the docs for mapbox-gl though. But yeah, the layers need to be added to the map before they can be toggled: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing it, here is the code if anyone wants to use it, this needs to be placed instead of geojson

```
 map.on('load', function() {
        // Add an image to use as a custom marker
        map.loadImage(
            'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/custom_marker.png',
            function(error, image) {
                if (error) throw error;
                map.addImage('custom-marker', image);
                // Add a GeoJSON source with 2 points
                map.addSource('points', {
                    'type': 'geojson',
                    'data': {
                        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                        'features': [
                            {
                                // feature for Mapbox DC
                                'type': 'Feature',
                                'geometry': {
                                    'type': 'Point',
                                    'coordinates': [
                                        -77.03238901390978,
                                        38.913188059745586
                                    ]
                                },
                                'properties': {
                                    'title': 'New York',
                                    'description':'undefined'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                // feature for Mapbox SF
                                'type': 'Feature',
                                'geometry': {
                                    'type': 'Point',
                                    'coordinates': [-122.414, 37.776]
                                },
                                'properties': {
                                    'title': 'Mapbox SF',
                                  'description': 'description sf'
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });

                // Add a symbol layer
                map.addLayer({
                    'id': 'points',
                    'type': 'symbol',
                    'source': 'points',
                    'layout': {
                        'icon-image': 'custom-marker',
                        // get the title name from the source's "title" property                     
                    
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    });





map.on('click', 'points', function(e) {
var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
var description = e.features[0].properties.description;
var title = e.features[0].properties.title;
 
// Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that multiple
// copies of the feature are visible, the popup appears
// over the copy being pointed to.
while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
}
 
new mapboxgl.Popup()
.setLngLat(coordinates)
.setHTML('<h3>' + title + '</h3><p>' + description + '</p>')
.addTo(map);
});



//code for toogle
//

// enumerate ids of the layers
var toggleableLayerIds = ['points', 'museums'];
 
// set up the corresponding toggle button for each layer
for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];
 
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = '#';
link.className = 'active';
link.textContent = id;
 
link.onclick = function(e) {
var clickedLayer = this.textContent;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
 
var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility');
 
// toggle layer visibility by changing the layout object's visibility property
if (visibility === 'visible') {
map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
this.className = '';
} else {
this.className = 'active';
map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'visible');
}
};
 
var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
layers.appendChild(link);
}
```